# Cordova remove file

Tags: cordova

I have a working app that creates a file.
I'm looking for a way to remove files from a cordova app after some hours of work. I can't seem to make it work.

here is the code for creating and deleting files :

```js
    function crea(){
        alert(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dir) {
            alert("got main dir",dir);
            dir.getFile("log1.txt", {create:true}, function(file) {
                alert("got the file", file);
                            
            });
        });
            }



        function del(){
    var relativeFilePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    var filename = "log1.txt"; 
    alert(relativeFilePath);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
      //  alert(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
        fileSystem.root.getFile(relativeFilePath + filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.remove(function(file){
                alert("File removed!");
            },function(){
                alert("error deleting the file " + error.code);
                });
            },function(){
                alert("file does not exist");
            });
        },function(evt){
            alert(evt.target.error.code);
    });
    
    }
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it works :

```
function del() {

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function (dir) {

        dir.getFile("log1.txt", {create: false}, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.remove(function (file) {
                alert("file removed!");
            }, function (error) {
                alert("error occurred: " + error.code);
            }, function () {
                alert("file does not exist");
            });
        });
    });

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your error handler needs to have "error" passed to it for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

It also works with just using `requestFileSystem` instead of `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('test.txt', {
        create: false,
        exclusive: false
    }, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.remove(function (file) {
            // File deleted successfully
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err); // Error while removing File
        });

    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err)  // Error while requesting File.
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err)  // Error while requesting FS
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
removeFile(path) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const filePath = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, (dir) => {
    const fileName = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    dir.getFile(fileName, { create: false }, (fileEntry) => {
      fileEntry.remove(() => {
        resolve('file removed!');
      }, (error) => reject('error occurred: ' + error.code),
        () => reject('file does not exist'));
    }, (error) => reject(error));
  }, (error) => reject(error));
});
```

}